# Javascript JSON transverse with hierarchical output

Tags: javascript, json, tree

Im trying to read a JSON schema but can't seem to work out how to output into hierarchical structure with all the previous objects etc.

This is JSON Response Scheme

```
{
"Shopping": {
"Orders": {
  "OrderInfo": {
    "OrderNumber": "D0102864",
    "ContactID": "AS76372",
    "OrderDate": "01/01/2018",
    "Billing": {
      "BillingID": "B673472",
      "Name": "Fred Smith"
    },
    "Delivery": {
      "DeliveryID": "D769397",
      "Name": "Joe Blogg"
    },
    "Discount": {
      "DiscountValue": "10"
    },
    "OrderProduct": {
      "NumberofItems": "1",
      "Items": {
        "Item": {
          "ProductID": "P5763868",
          "ItemName": "Big Blue Box",
          "Price": "10",
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

With multiple items array is added []

```
{
 "Shopping": {
"Orders": {
  "OrderInfo": {
    "OrderNumber": "D0102864",
    "ContactID": "AS76372",
    "OrderDate": "01/01/2018",
    "Billing": {
      "BillingID": "B673472",
      "Name": "Fred Smith"
    },
    "Delivery": {
      "DeliveryID": "D769397",
      "Name": "Joe Blogg"
    },
    "Discount": {
      "DiscountValue": "10"
    },
    "OrderProduct": {
      "NumberofItems": "2",
      "Items": {
        "Item": [
          {
          "ProductID": "P5763868",
          "ItemName": "Big Blue Box",
          "Price": "10",
          },
          {
          "ProductID": "P57638262",
          "ItemName": "Big Red Box",
          "Price": "20",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Within the following javascript function, Im try to generate the output structure Object_nestedObject_Keyname like the example further below. Just a note, the JSON is an Ajax call along with other data, but i need to transverse the shopping object only.

```
 function js_traverse(o) {
 var type = typeof o 
 if (type == "object") {

    for (var key in o) {

        console.log("key: ", key)
        js_traverse(o[key])
    }
  } else {
    console.log("value: ",o)
  }
 }

 js_traverse(data['Shopping']); <- above scheme
```

and Im trying to create the following output in console log sort of a tree structure

```
 Orders
 Orders_OrdersInfo
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderNumber
 Orders_OrdersInfo_ContactID
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderDate
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Billing
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Billing_BillingID
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Billing_Name
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Delivery
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Delivery_DeliveryID
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Delivery_Name
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Discount
 Orders_OrdersInfo_Discount_DiscountValue
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_NumberofItems
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_Items
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_ProductID_1 <-- increment number at end if multiple item
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_ItemName_1 <-- increment at end if multiple item
 Orders_OrdersInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_Price_1 <-- increment at end if multiple item
```

Comment: why do you need the numbers starting with one instead of taking the index?

Comment: Thanks, thats fine I can use the index instead

Comment: is ther only one array inside? why is the number at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach by checking the value and the type then take either kthe keys or display the path of the object.

```js
function getKeys(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(k => iter(o[k], p.concat(k)));
        } else {
            console.log(p.join('_'));
        }
    }
    iter(object, []);
}

var object = { Shopping: { Orders: { OrderInfo: { OrderNumber: "D0102864", ContactID: "AS76372", OrderDate: "01/01/2018", Billing: { BillingID: "B673472", Name: "Fred Smith" }, Delivery: { DeliveryID: "D769397", Name: "Joe Blogg" }, Discount: { DiscountValue: "10" }, OrderProduct: { NumberofItems: "2", Items: { Item: [{ ProductID: "P5763868", ItemName: "Big Blue Box", Price: "10" }, { ProductID: "P57638262", ItemName: "Big Red Box", Price: "20" }] } } } } } };

getKeys(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Additional function for generatoig an array/object out of a given array with keys and a value. This works with a check if the given key is a number.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce((o, k, i, kk) => o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}), object)[last] = value;
}

function getValues(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(k => iter(o[k], p.concat(k)));
        } else {
            result.push([p, o]);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var object = { Shopping: { Orders: { OrderInfo: { OrderNumber: "D0102864", ContactID: "AS76372", OrderDate: "01/01/2018", Billing: { BillingID: "B673472", Name: "Fred Smith" }, Delivery: { DeliveryID: "D769397", Name: "Joe Blogg" }, Discount: { DiscountValue: "10" }, OrderProduct: { NumberofItems: "2", Items: { Item: [{ ProductID: "P5763868", ItemName: "Big Blue Box", Price: "10" }, { ProductID: "P57638262", ItemName: "Big Red Box", Price: "20" }] } } } } } },
    values = getValues(object),
    objectFromValues = {};

values.forEach(([keys, value]) => setValue(objectFromValues, keys, value));

console.log(objectFromValues);
console.log(values)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow thats fast! Thanks Nina. Going to try it out within my setup

Comment: Is it possible to reconstruct the above function output like  'Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber' etc back into an JSON schema? Lets say 'Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber' etc were all fields id/names and I need to construct their keys and values back into the JSON schema.

Comment: Thank you Nina, thats great. However, if the data values were now taken from  <input type="text" name="Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber" id="Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber"> fields (instead of a JSON object/array) and then recompiled into a JSON object how is that possible? So like your code above but data gathered from a fields to generate the JSON schema.

Comment: then take the splitted by `'_'` name as path and the value as value. or do i miss something?

Comment: So to make it clear, first part of this question (right at the top) was to create the fields (Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber) from the JSON then the second part is grab the values of the fields and reconstruct the JSON along with objects keys and values like the schema above (first part).

Comment: (1) response JSON -> into fields with id/name like Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber (2) Fields Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber -> into JSON schema -> then request out

Comment: Nina is it possible to contact you through a freelance website or email?

Comment: @Dev, it would be easier, if you ask a new question about the missing pices and not in the comments of a kind of related but not belonging to the answer. there you could add the html part as well.

Comment: Hi Nina I've added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140605/taking-form-field-names-and-values-creating-a-json-schema