# Taking form field names and values creating a JSON Schema

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I have a form that is generated by a JSON response and each field name (Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_ContactID) contains a nested object structure

so for instance this JSON part

```
 "Shopping": {
  "Orders": {
   "OrderInfo": {
     "OrderNumber": "",
```

will construct the following field name

```
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber" value="D0102864">
```

Here are the other fields

```
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_ContactID" value="AS76372">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderDate" value="01/01/2018">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Billing_BillingID" value="B673472">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Billing_Name" value="Fred Smith">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Delivery_DeliveryID" value="D769397">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Delivery_Name" value="Joe Blogg">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Discount_DiscountValue" value="10">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_NumberofItems" value="1">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_ProductID" value="P5763868">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_ItemName" value="Big Blue Box">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_Price" value="10">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_ProductID" value="P57638262">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_ItemName" value="Big Red Box">
 <input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_Price" value="20">
```

I need a Javascript function that will grab the above fields names and its values and reconstruct a JSON scheme like below. Basically it looks at the field name and works out the nested objects/arrays and keys with values.

```
 {
  "Shopping": {
  "Orders": {
   "OrderInfo": {
    "OrderNumber": "D0102864",
    "ContactID": "AS76372",
    "OrderDate": "01/01/2018",
    "Billing": {
     "BillingID": "B673472",
     "Name": "Fred Smith"
     },
    "Delivery": {
    "DeliveryID": "D769397",
     "Name": "Joe Blogg"
     },
     "Discount": {
      "DiscountValue": "10"
      },
     "OrderProduct": {
      "NumberofItems": "2",
       "Items": {
        "Item": [
        {
         "ProductID": "P5763868",
         "ItemName": "Big Blue Box",
         "Price": "10",
         },
        {
         "ProductID": "P57638262",
         "ItemName": "Big Red Box",
         "Price": "20",
        }
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Below is a function that im trying to reflect the above process

```
function setValue(object, path, value) {
var last = path.pop();

path.reduce((o, k, i, kk) => o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? 
kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}), object)[last] = value;
}

function getValues(object) {
function iter(o, p) {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => iter(o[k], p.concat(k)));
    } else {
        result.push([p, o]);
    }
}

var result = [];
iter(object, []);
return result;
 }

//// here im not sure how to grab the fields and values from above 
var object = data['shopping'],
values = getValues(object),
objectFromValues = {};


 values.forEach(([keys, value]) => setValue(objectFromValues, keys, value));

  console.log(objectFromValues);
  console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take all input elements and take the name and split it by underscore for the path of the new object and the value and build a new object with the given information.

`allInputs` is an array like object which is iterable by borrowing an array method.

In `setValue`, the reduce callback checks if the next key is a stringed numerical value and takes an array as default object instead of an object.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce((o, k, i, kk) => o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}), object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {},
    allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(allInputs, ({ name, value }) => setValue(object, name.split('_'), value));

console.log(object);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderNumber" value="D0102864">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_ContactID" value="AS76372">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderDate" value="01/01/2018">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Billing_BillingID" value="B673472">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Billing_Name" value="Fred Smith">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Delivery_DeliveryID" value="D769397">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Delivery_Name" value="Joe Blogg">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_Discount_DiscountValue" value="10">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_NumberofItems" value="1">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_ProductID" value="P5763868">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_ItemName" value="Big Blue Box">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_0_Price" value="10">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_ProductID" value="P57638262">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_ItemName" value="Big Red Box">
<input type="text" name="Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_Items_Item_1_Price" value="20">
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you soo much Nina. Been hours trying to get it work right. Im going to select this as the top answer straight away! One tiny thought, Shopping_Orders_OrderInfo_OrderProduct_NumberofItems wouldn't really be a field, it simply increments based on the number of items in the array Item": [{